# How to find oldest and newest file in a directory?

Tags: python

My code should find the newest and oldest files in a folder and its subfolders. It works for the top-level folder but it doesn't include files within subfolders.

```
import os
import glob

mypath = 'C:/RDS/*'

print(min(glob.glob(mypath), key=os.path.getmtime))
print(max(glob.glob(mypath), key=os.path.getmtime))
```

How do I make it recurse into the subfolders?

Comment: FYI there is no distinction between 'directory' and 'folder'. They are the same thing.

Comment: What if there are multiple files with identical oldest or newest dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pathlib, also `getmtime` gives the last modified time, you want the time file was created so use `getctime`

if you strictly want only files:

```
import os
import pathlib

mypath = 'your path'
taggedrootdir = pathlib.Path(mypath)
print(min([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getctime))
print(max([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getctime))
```

if results may include folders:

```
import os
import pathlib

mypath = 'your path'
taggedrootdir = pathlib.Path(mypath)
print(min(taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*'), key=os.path.getctime))
print(max(taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*'), key=os.path.getctime))
```

Comment: but Abhi , i have folder inside RDS which is oldest compared to the file inside folder which is inside RDS

Comment: Hi @AuroraEugene, what is the problem that you are facing now, did this code not work, could you elaborate please.

Comment: so Abhi , i have some files inside RDS , and some folder for example ,consider BMC as a folder which is inside RDS , and BMC has some files , so here in your code it is returning some filename from BMC as the oldest file but at the same time i have some other file out side BMC which is older than the file returned

Comment: Hi, @AuroraEugene Ive updated the answer, replaced `getmtime` with `getctime`, I've explained it in the answer.

Comment: Seems wasteful to create a temporary list of files twice and (implicitly) go through each finding the min or max when you could just create the list once, sort it by date, and then take the first and last  files of the result.

Comment: @martineau true, but this is just for demonstration. I'm assuming op would have optimized it when adding it to an actual project.

Comment: Well, it's arguably too much overhead to ignore, so I've posted an [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69799855/355230).

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) show, you can add a `recursive=True` keyword argument to `glob.glob()`

so your code becomes:

```
import os
import glob

mypath = 'C:/RDS/*'

print(min(glob.glob(mypath, recursive=True), key=os.path.getmtime))
print(max(glob.glob(mypath, recursive=True), key=os.path.getmtime))
```

This should give you the oldest and newest file in your folder and all its subfolders.

Comment: C:/RDS/1.py
C:/RDS/3

C:/RDS/1.py
C:/RDS/3       Same result , it just considers the files inside RDS and not files inside folder inside RDS folder

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the os filepath separator: "/" (on unix) vs. "\" (on windows).
You can try something like below.
It saves the files list in a variable, it is faster than traversing twice the file system.
There is one line for debugging, comment it in production.

```
import os
import glob

mypath = 'D:\RDS\**'

allFilesAndFolders = glob.glob(mypath, recursive=True)
# just for debugging
print(allFilesAndFolders)

print(min(allFilesAndFolders, key=os.path.getmtime))
print(max(allFilesAndFolders, key=os.path.getmtime))
```

Comment: Note to OP: if you ever need the path separator, use `os.path.sep`. or simply use `os.path.join(...)` to correctly join fragments of a path with the correct separator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly efficient way of doing it. It determines the oldest and newest files by iterating through them all once. Since it uses iteration, there's no need to first create a list of them and go through it twice to determine the two extremes.

```
mport os
import pathlib

def max_min(iterable, keyfunc=None):
    if keyfunc is None:
        keyfunc = lambda x: x  # Identity.

    iterator = iter(iterable)
    most = least = next(iterator)
    mostkey = leastkey = keyfunc(most)

    for item in iterator:
        key = keyfunc(item)
        if key > mostkey:
            most = item
            mostkey = key
        elif key < leastkey:
            least = item
            leastkey = key
    return most, least


mypath = '.'
files = (f for f in pathlib.Path(mypath).resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file())
oldest, newest = max_min(files, keyfunc=os.path.getmtime)
print(f'oldest file: {oldest}')
print(f'newest file: {newest}')
```